# TLSv1.2 support in CentOS 5.8

Tags: centos, openssl, ssl

Right now I can't access HTTPS site from PhantomJS headless WebKit browser because of TLSv1.2

In my CentOS 5.8 I have following OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008 verison installed.

I think I need to upgrade my OpenSSL lib in order to support TLSv1.2. Am I right ? If so, could you please show me an example how it can be achieved ?

Comment: You can check whether your version supports TLSv1.2 by running the following command: `openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -tls1_2`.  If you get an error message with usage info, then it is not supported.  If you get a connection and see certificates and session keys etc, then you have TLSv1.2 in your version of openssl.  Note press Ctl-C to exit.

Comment: One way to achieve this would be to use [copr](https://copr.fedoraproject.org/) to build openssl for your version of CentOS using the source RPMs from later versions as an example/template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build OpenSSL manually - https://miteshshah.github.io/linux/centos/how-to-enable-openssl-1-0-2-a-tlsv1-1-and-tlsv1-2-on-centos-5-and-rhel5/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you more easily:

There are a lot of people still running RHEL 5 / CentOS 5 for several reasons. Unfortunately RHEL 5 is out of support and additionally there was never a package with OpenSSL >= 1 for RHEL 5.

If you don't have any concerns about using a foreign repo then you can use "tuxad repo". It provides a different and more easy way **to update OpenSSL of RHEL 5 to the one of RHEL 6** (<s>which is still supported</s> which was longer supported):

1. Install tuxad repo for RHEL 5: rpm -i http://www.tuxad.de/repo/5/tuxad.rpm
2. Update packages: yum update

More details can be found here:

[www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2014/11/19/openssl_updatesenhancements_for_rhel__centos_5](http://www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2014/11/19/openssl_updatesenhancements_for_rhel__centos_5/index.html)
[www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2018/07/21/tuxad_rh5_repo_now_with_phpopenssl1](http://www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2018/07/21/tuxad_rh5_repo_now_with_phpopenssl1/index.html)

This repo contains several packages which are rebuild against OpenSSL 1:

- httpd (also include other enhancements like ECDH support)
- postfix
- dovecot
- curl
- lynx
- mutt
- vsftpd
- w3m
- wget
- php
- php from RHEL 6 backported (in separate repo "tuxad-php")